# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.Tried all the solution but still not

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

> Console Error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
        at com.ayush.JavaApi.main(JavaApi.java:10)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

> pom.xml

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.ayush</groupId>
      <artifactId>JavaCourse</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>



      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    </project>
```

> JavaClass with Main Method

```
package com.ayush;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class JavaApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(JavaApi.class,args);
    }

}
```

***I am running this program as java application but it is giving me error. i have try all the solution and also provided in the stackoverflow which is updating the maven but it is not working and still giving me the error.
thanks for the help in advance.***

Comment: Did you try a rebuild(clean/build) ?

Comment: how are you running?  Command line, eclipse, intellij?

Comment: How are you running the code? Seems you classpath is wrong.

Comment: Yes i did this too jonathan johx thanks for help

Comment: i am using sts IDE Taylor thanks for the help

Comment: i have checked that Andreas thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've copied all your files to Intellij but it had no issue with your file. 
Maybe hierarchical structure of your project (class JavaApi should be in JavaCourse package) or IDE setting (clean/rebuild, reimport pom) is wrong.

For beginning with Spring boot. You can generate project from https://start.spring.io/

Comment: okay thanks for the help but i have created another project with different name but error still appears.

Comment: when you created the project in the intellij then was it running with no error.[NgocDex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10911410/ngocdex)

Comment: you can try removing all file in .m2 repository folder of maven, then re build your project again

Comment: Tried that too [NgocDex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10911410/ngocdex).I am unable to solve it.thanks for the help brother.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Project and created it again .It worked for me .Thanks everyone for the help